Lists stored in react-query to only contain an array of id values
I have a useQuery that fetches a list of items. In my queryFn, I'm only storing the id values for these items and I'm using the select option to fetch the actual full object of my items from their individual cache.
How can I get select to be called again when any of the individual item's cache gets updated?
Example query:
export const useItems = () => {
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

return useQuery({
  queryKey: ['items'],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const items = await fetch();

    items.forEach((i) => queryClient.setQueryData(['items', i.id], () => i));

    return items.map((i) => i.id));
  },
  select: (ids) => {
    return ids.map((id) => queryClient.getQueryData(['items', id]))
  },
});
};

Now if I have a mutation hook that creates or updates an item, I then have it setQueryData for the item.
When I do this, I'm not seeing select get called again. The only way I'm able to get select to be called again is if I alter the actual contents of what is stored in the cache for ['items'].
I have to store a lot of data and I don't want to have duplicated data between whats in the lists vs what is in the individual caches.
